# Is it possible to redirect a Google Apps (sub)domain to an external URL?

Tags: google-workspace

I'm using Google Apps to handle my personal email under my own domain. I would like to redirect (when it comes to typing a URL in a browser) traffic from the "naked domain" or at least a subdomain to my Facebook profile or an about.me page etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Trust Google Apps have no connection in current request - this must be completed via hosting company control panel. Simply create new subdomain and upload there index file which to complete redirection using: 'PHP Header()', 'JavaScript refresh tag' etc. Also is possible .htaccess file uploaded on subdomain's root directory to complete such redirection.